# How to conditionally route and set paths in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need to conditionally route to 2 pages in my angular app ,

My Route.ts file

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'exampleInfo', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'invalid', component:InvalidComponent},
```

Somewhere in the app i am setting the router to navigate to 'invalid' based on some condition .
Now when i hit my URL , it opens the exampleInfo page for a fraction of a second and then redirects to invalid component .

How can i directly navigate to invalid component without hitting the default component conditionally ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please consider AOT compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [router guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) with `canActivate`

In the `canActivate` function you can check the condition. If its invalid you can route to your `InvalidComponent` else the guard let you go through the normal page.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'exampleInfo', canActivate: [YourGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'invalid', component:InvalidComponent},
```

This will happen befor you even enter the `exampleInfo` page.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the possibility to switch the components in the routes array.
Could this be of help to you?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'exampleInfo', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'invalid', component:InvalidComponent},
  { path: 'exampleInfo', component: (() => {
      return SomeService.staticMethod() ? ExampleInfoComponent : InvalidComponent;
    })() }
  ...
]
```

edit: However, as you may see, for this solution you need to be able to offer a static method, e.g. in a service, but a component should work as well, that can return true/false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below  :

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'SomePath', redirectTo: 'exampleInfo', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'invalid', component:InvalidComponent},
  { path: '**', component:InvalidComponent}
```

you can use some path for example info and add last line any other route will take you to invalid component.

Answer (score 0):

If your invalid component has a specific set of conditions that should trigger showing it, consider using a route guard on the pages that should not be accessible in this state that re-routes to the invalid component.

The advantage of this is that you seperate your "where should a user be" logic from the templates themselves, so your component won't initialise before it realises the user shouldn't be there.